# Parent Name not showing in the related list

Tags: page-layout, related-list

I want to show the child records with Related list single, but I can't find the parent name in the option in the page layout. Does anyone know why? Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. May I ask why you'd want to show the parent record name on the related list of a child record on the parent record page layout? You'd already see the parent record name at the top of the page, and it will be the same for all child records anyway.

Comment: I just wondering why it's not showing but you are right. Showing parent name is useless since it is already in parent record. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to display the lookup-related fields in the related list and I am also wondering why you want to show the parent name which will be same for all related list records.

But still if you want to display then here are the two options

1. Create a Custom Related List Component:
   You can create a custom Lightning Web Component (LWC) that fetches and displays the required fields from the child records related to the parent record. The custom LWC can use Apex to query the related records and present the data on the parent record page. Once the custom component is created, you can place it on the parent record page using the Lightning App Builder.
2. Use Custom Formula Fields:
   Another approach is to use custom formula fields on the parent object. You can create formula fields on the child object to pull in specific fields from the related parent records using a reference to the lookup relationship.

Let me know if you need any help with the above two approaches.

Comment: Thanks. I think LWC would be my option since it currently is in a narrow region, so it can only be viewed in the Tile list. Is it possible to create an LWC button and this button will open the list view in salesforce tab similar to the view all button of the related list?